# How to display and select a nested object graph in a single row of a <p:dataTable>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have two models as follows.

`Country`

```
public class Country{
    private String countryName;
    private List<State> states;

    // Getters/setters.
}
```

`State`

```
public class State{
    private String stateName;
    private String stateCode;

    // Getters/setters.
}
```

In my backing bean I have a `List<Country>` property.

How do I display it in my `<p:dataTable>` as follows?

[image]

And once an user select a row, how do I get both the country and state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kolossus made very good suggestions, but actually it is highly possible that none of them will give you the presentation of data you want. So I propose a third way: modify the model a bit to account for your view needs. It is necessary to do that because every row in `<p:dataTable>` is composed of a *currently iterated* element from your list and that iteration is the only iteration. So in order to achieve your functionality you shall provide all the row information you need within the iterated element, by basically modifying the model presentation.

One of the approaches is to create an additional class containing `Country` and `State` objects (or alternatively the string properties you need to display):

```
public class CountryState {
    private Country country;
    private State state;
}
```

create a list for iteration 'on the fly' (or alternatively beforehand):

```
public List<CountryState> getCountryStates(List<Country> countries) {
    List<CountryState> lst = new ArrayList<CountryState>();
    for(Country country : countries) {
        for(State state : country.getState()) {
            lst.add(new CountryState(country, state);
        }
    }
    return lst;
}
```

and use it in your datatable:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.countryStates}" var="cs">
    <p:column headerText="Country name">  
        <h:outputText value="#{cs.country.name}" />  
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="State name">  
        <h:outputText value="#{cs.state.name}" />  
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="State code">  
        <h:outputText value="#{cs.state.code}" />  
    </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Alternatively, you may consider using [`<p:panelGrid>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panelGrid.jsf) if you want to unite rows/columns.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Nested Datatable: Simply drop another datatable in a column for each row of an outer datatable:

   ```
   <p:dataTable var="country" value="#{myBean.countries}">
      <p:column>
           <h:outputText value="#{country.name}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
           <p:dataTable var="state" value="#{country.states}">
               <p:column>
                  <p:outputText value="#{state.name}"/>
               </p:column>
               <p:column>
                  <p:commandButton value="select">
                    <f:param name="state" value="#{state}"/>
                    <f:param name="country" value="#{country}"/>
                  </p:commmandButton>
               </p:column>
           </p:dataTable>
        </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
   ```
2. Primefaces [expandable rows](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableExpandableRows.jsf): This IMO scales and looks better

   ```
     <p:dataTable var="country" value="#{myBean.countries}">
        <p:column>
           <h:outputText value="#{country.name}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:row expansion>
           <p:datalist value ="#{country.states} var="state">
               #{state.name}
           </p:datalist>
        </p:row expansion>
     </p:dataTable>
   ```

Comment: Good suggestions (+1 of course), but I think OP wanted the other thing and that is a slight model modificaion.

Answer (score 1):

One way i can suggest to you create a Third Bean which will contain Both Country and State object..But here issue is that how can you show Country then state in same row because here issue is that A Country have plenty of states..How some one know Which country have which state? 
The another way is that you can show Country then all state for that country but its look and feel will be too weird because you are using DataTable here . It will good if you explain your thought also with your question ,why you want to do it.

Comment: If a country have 5 States. I want country name to appear in all state rows. I'm using PRIMEFACES_DATA_TABLE not DATA_LIST.

Comment: Is this any issue to use another bean for this which contain state as well as country